# Table field names mixed up in table view of ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, file-geodatabase, table

I'm having trouble figuring out why apparently a table from a file geodatabase isn't interpreted correctly. These are some of the fields as they should show up in the table view:

[image]

However, the table view doesn't show the right headers and also mixes up values:

[image]

In that image,

- the column marked with "1" should be named "idia_r"
- the column marked with "2" should be named "flow_r"
- the column marked with "3" is fine.

When I join this table to a line feature class (also from a file geodatabase, but a different one), I get the same mixup in column names. Again, the property window shows the right attributes:

[image]

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do your fields have any aliases set for their names in either the geodatabase table or the map's table view that you are showing here?

Comment: indeed there's a pair of "shifted" aliases for "idia_r" (alias "flow_r") "flow_r" (alias "velocity_r"). Can you put this into an answer? I'll have to fix a lot of tables now (about 2100).

Answer (score 2):

I would check whether your fields have any aliases set for their names in either the geodatabase table or the map's table view that you are showing here.

These should be apparent by opening either the table view properties or the table properties via the Table of Contents or the Catalog window respectively.

I think there should be a Fields tab present in both of those Properties dialogs.